# dynamically add IEnumerable<int?> on group by result set in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, c#-3.0

Can any suggest me to figure out this requirement.

```
var enableIds = context.items.Where(tble => tble.Date == null)
                         .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
                         .Select(g => new
        {
            Id = g.Key,
            EId = g.Select(c => c.EId).Distinct()
        });
```

For above query i'm getting below result set

"Id\":1,\"EId\":[1,2]

Now i've to add -1 value to  EId dynamically  like this ("EId\":[1,2,-1] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an [Enumerable Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension:

```
 var enableIds = context.items.Where(tble => tble.Date == null)
                     .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
                     .Select(g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        EId = g.Select(c => c.EId).Distinct()).ToList().Concat(new[] { -1 })
    });
```

Comment: it is giving an error like this "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator."

Comment: You should mention in your question that you are using Linq2Sql and not simply Linq. I updated my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to without using foreach loop.

Comment: ToList before Concat should do it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've find solution here is my code.`var i = new List<int> { -1 };
var enableIds = context.items.Where(tble => tble.Date == null).ToList().GroupBy(a => a.Id).Select(g => new
            {
                Id = g.Key,
                EId = g.Select(c => c.EId).Distinct().Concat(i)
            });`

Comment: I am glad you made it. Just to make sure that you know what your solution means. Your Linq2Sql is finishing after the first `ToList` call, so at that point you are fetching all items which match your Where clause and put them into list. After that pure linq is in  play with which you do `GroupBy` and `Select` calls. Those two operations are not translated into SQL query, they are done in memory on the previously fetched list of items.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this using a helper method `Concat<T>`. The helper method could be implemented as an extension method for the `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
var enableIds = _db.items.Where(tble => tble.Date == null)
                         .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
                         .Select(g => new 
      { 
          Id = g.Key, 
          EId = Concat(g.Select(c => c.EId).Distinct(), -1) 
      });


        public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable, params T[] enumerable2)
        {
            if (enumerable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable");
            if (enumerable2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("enumerable2");

            foreach (T t in enumerable)
            {
                yield return t;
            }

            foreach (T t in enumerable2)
            {
                yield return t;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is working giving compile time error like this "Cannot assign void to anonymous type property"